# Companions "Glory of the Dead" bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On the PS3, I can't get the Glory of the Dead quest from Vilkas, I only get "Jobs" from Vilkas and the other two leaders. I have done all other Companions quests.